# Basic table format within Cmd Window

Tags: java, string

I am looking for a way to format integers within the command window into a simple table.  I know there are ways to create tables using swing (JPanel; JFrame) but I am looking for resources on how to be able to format Strings into columns for easy display within the command window.

Any detailed resources to reference or code examples would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try the overloaded variants of [`PrintStream.printf(..)`].  (`System.out` is a `PrintStream`.)

Comment: Thank you Andrew.  I am a beginner as you can probably tell.  So PrintStream is a different class then String?  If so I am assuming there are a bunch of methods I can use under PrintStream as opposed to String.

Comment: Try checking the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/).  A marvelous resource for that type of question.  And it's typically a lot faster than asking me when I'm spending time flipping between SO & reading silly articles on Cracked.com.  ;)